# mdx ssis dynamic table

Tags: ssis, mdx

In a SSIS package, I have a DataSource and DataDestination. I want in the DataDestination, the destination table be created dynamically.
I shouldn't have anything else (SQLTask ...) because I'm using mdx query.
How can I do that?

Comment: Data destination is a sql table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a script task, and using it I executed my scripts using ado.net